# empty space betweeen two <div>

Tags: html

I do know some PHP and some HTML, but I have no answer to the following question: Please take a look at http://www.show-my-homework.com. There are two widgets on the right column. The top is an ad (from media.net), the bottom is an widget (from insticator). Between them there is a big empty space although the two  follow one after the other. Can someone tell me why the big vertical empty space appears, please?

```
    </div> <!-- /.col.grid-70 -->
        <div class="grid-30 tablet-grid-30 mobile-grid-100">

    <div id="secondary" class="widget-area" role="complementary">
        <aside id="search-2" class="widget widget_search"><form role="search" method="get" class="search-form" action="http://www.show-my-homework.com/">
            <label>
                <span class="screen-reader-text">Search for:</span>
                <input type="search" class="search-field" placeholder="Search &hellip;" value="" name="s" />
            </label>
            <input type="submit" class="search-submit" value="Search" />
        </form></aside><aside id="text-12" class="widget widget_text">          <div class="textwidget"><script id="mNCC" language="javascript">
   medianet_width = "300";
   medianet_height = "250";
   medianet_crid = "185484698";
   medianet_versionId = "111299";
   (function() {
       var isSSL = 'https:' == document.location.protocol;
       var mnSrc = (isSSL ? 'https:' : 'http:') + '//contextual.media.net    /nmedianet.js?cid=8CU50RQ95' + (isSSL ? '&https=1' : '');
   document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" id="mNSC" src="' + mnSrc + '"></scr' + 'ipt>');
   })();
</script>

</div>
        </aside><aside id="insticator-embed-2" class="widget insticator-embed-class"><!-- Insticator API Fire Widget --><div id="insticator-container"><div id="div-insticator-ad-1" adonis-marker></div><div id="insticator-embed"></div><div id="div-insticator-ad-2" adonis-marker></div><script data-cfasync='false' type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/Insticator.ad.loadAd("div-insticator-ad-1");Insticator.ad.loadAd("div-insticator-ad-2");Insticator.load("em",{id : "495751ba-23d2-4424-8f44-6a20816feab8"})/*]]>*/</script></div><!-- End Insticator API Fire Widget --></aside>
    </div> <!-- /#secondary.widget-area -->

</div> <!-- /.grid-30 -->

</div> <!-- /#primary.grid-container.site-content -->
```

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in an [mcve] *in the question itself*, **not only on a third-party site**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this: `<div id="div-insticator-ad-1" adonis-marker="" style="width:300px;height:250px;" data-google-query-id="CKaF8PCF5tMCFQaPGAodLl8ObA">`

It says `height:250px`, that is what you see there, it is basically an empty div.

Code:

```
<aside id="insticator-embed-2" class="widget insticator-embed-class">
   <!-- Insticator API Fire Widget -->
   <div id="insticator-container" style="position: relative;">
      <div id="div-insticator-ad-1" adonis-marker="" style="width:300px;height:250px;" data-google-query-id="CKaF8PCF5tMCFQaPGAodLl8ObA">
         <div id="google_ads_iframe_/91725235/show-my-homework.com_Web_300x250_1_0__container__" style="border: 0pt none;"><iframe id="google_ads_iframe_/91725235/show-my-homework.com_Web_300x250_1_0" title="3rd party ad content" name="google_ads_iframe_/91725235/show-my-homework.com_Web_300x250_1_0" width="300" height="250" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="0" srcdoc="" style="border: 0px; vertical-align: bottom;"></iframe></div>
      </div>
      <div id="insticator-embed" style="height: 350px;width: 300px;"><iframe id="insticator-embed-iframe" src="about:blank" height="100%" width="100%" style="border-color: rgb(4, 51, 255); border-style: solid; border-width: 2px; user-select: none; box-sizing: border-box;"></iframe></div>
      <div id="div-insticator-ad-2" adonis-marker=""></div>
      <script data-cfasync="false" type="text/javascript">/*<![CDATA[*/Insticator.ad.loadAd("div-insticator-ad-1");Insticator.ad.loadAd("div-insticator-ad-2");Insticator.load("em",{id : "495751ba-23d2-4424-8f44-6a20816feab8"})/*]]>*/</script>
   </div>
   <!-- End Insticator API Fire Widget -->
</aside>
```

Comment: I understand, there should be an ad from insticator above the widget in that place. Thank you.